# Unidentified hair between CSS-generated icons

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

I am creating these icons as an image wrapped with a CSS circle behind it. Yet, this random bit of hair looks like it is stemming from the CSS.

Any explanations why? Sorry the CSS is all inline - this is for an html email:

```
<div style="width: 180px; text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;">
<a href="http://pinterest.com/houseplansdan/">
<li style="list-style: none; background-color: #505050;width: 40px;height: 40px;border-radius: 20px; display: inline-block;margin-right: 10px;">
<img style="padding-top: 5px;"src="http://homeplan.com/newsletter/October/img/icons/32x32_pinterest.png" href="http://pinterest.com/houseplansdan/">
</li>
</a>    

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Houseplans/91152065546">
<li style="background-color: #505050;width: 40px;height: 40px;border-radius: 20px; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;">
<img style="padding-top: 5px;"src="http://homeplan.com/newsletter/October/img/icons/32x32_facebook.png">
</li>
</a>    

<a href="http://twitter.com/houseplans_">
<li style="list-style: none; background-color: #505050; width: 40px;height: 40px;border-radius: 20px; display: inline-block;">
<img style="padding-top: 5px;"src="http://homeplan.com/newsletter/October/img/icons/32x32_twitter.png">
</li>
</a>  
</div>​
```

Fiddle version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pHksF/1/).

Comment: Did you try with several different *recent* browsers?

Comment: @meagar I don't understand why not a jsfiddle link? Almost all the questions have it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Questions and answers should be self contained, extra links are fine but only as a compliment to the post, it shouldn't be the *only* content. Still, meager was wrong to outright remove it rather than port the code over as MichaelMrozek has done. And I personally have had jsfiddle be unavailable for hours while I could access SO, just to give one example of why it hurts to rely on external links. If the site goes down, the post is useless - not good.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Okay, what if I need to check what is wrong with it? Since it was a fiddle, I was able to give an instant answer. If it isn't I would need to create one and then explain the stuff. You got it? Many of these kind of questions I have answered, or asked, will surely accompany a fiddle. If none is there, I explicitly ask for one. It is actually better, you see.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Feel free to search/ask on [meta]. I don't have time to go over this (again)  right now. Bottom line: external demos are helpful, but not required, and should not be the only way to access the code.

Comment: Lol, okay fine. Lemme give it as a suggestion! :)

Comment: You may have a jsfiddle link which *supplements* your answer. I remove jsfiddle links when they are the only content because it forces the user to edit their question into an acceptable state. It is not the job of other users to copy the jsfiddle code into the question, it is the job of the question's author. We cannot trim down an entire jsfiddle on behalf the asker, the asker must turn it into a short self-contained complete example. I *also* edit out jsfiddles because it prevents users from answering the question and rewarding bad behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be an `LI` inside an `A`. Please correct it, if possible.

Also, this **CSS** will fix:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }​
```

#### Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pHksF/2/

Comment: Yeah that HTML is all kinds of broken, but your edit still lacks a `<ul>` wrapper, and is still full of errors.

Comment: If I cannot wrap an LI inside an <a> then what do you suggest?

Comment: @JoeIsaacson: Put the `<a>`s inside the `<li>`s and wrap it all in a `<ul>`.

Comment: Put an inline element like `<span>`, `<em>`, `<strong>` or why do you need to wrap?

Comment: @WesleyMurch and Praveen - Thanks for the help pe eps

Answer (score 3):

That's not hair, it's `text-decoration` - the default style for links. Apply this to any links you don't want to have it:

```
​a { text-decoration:none; }​
```

You should have no issues doing this inline for your email, although it may be tedious.